# Flutter Windows App Debug, Link: fatal error LNK1104

Tags: windows, flutter, debugging, testing, flutter-windows

I was debugging on my flutter app on Windows platform but it got stuck, I thought it might be caused because of some error in my code. I terminated the session and restarted the debugging. But then this error was shown when I debugged on Windows.

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\vsc flutter\Be-Pass-Flutter\build\windows\runner\Debug\be_pass.exe' [C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\vsc flutter\Be-Pass-Flutter\build\windows\runner\be_pass.vcxproj]**

It is working on browser and mobile but not on windows. I need to run it on Windows.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Most probably the executable file `be_pass.exe` is still open. Try to kill it and build again.

Comment: Probably is your antivirus. Add your project folder to the exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

This is my way to resolve the same problem:

1. flutter clean
2. flutter pub get

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try this solutions:

1. flutter clean
2. close your antivirus
3. restart your pc or (search in Task Manager for "yourProgramName.exe" and end its task) (this worked for me).

Answer (score -1):

No solution yet. There is only solution to install windows SDK or close antivirus. and then run in windows otherwise you have to remove the dependancies which or not supported or creating truble to build windows app.